# Could not find generator formtastic_stylesheets

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to generate stylesheets from formtastic gem. I use windows 7.

I use Rails 3.2.1 and ruby 1.9.3p125. I have installed formtastic-2.2.1

I run the command:

```
rails generate formtastic_stylesheets.
```

It returns:

```
Could not find generator formtastic_stylesheets.
```

Comment: Improve your answer by clarifying the points and other options available while asking a question!!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should use: `rails generate formtastic:install` instead.
Also,

Rails 3.1 introduces an asset pipeline that allows plugins like Formtastic to serve their own Stylesheets, Javascripts, etc without having to run generators that copy them across to the host application. Formtastic makes three stylesheets available as an Engine, you just need to require them in your global stylesheets.

```
# app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
*= require formtastic
*= require my_formtastic_changes`
```